# Docker - Package installation strange behavior

Tags: python-2.7, docker, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to build an an image with the help of Docker file. The docker file contains few snippets here.

`from ubuntu:latest   RUN apt-get update   RUN apt-get -y install python-pip`

I was build able to build the image in Windows machine.

Now, I used the same Docker file in AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18 machine.
Here the docker engine is not able to locate the package python-pip

I should able to build the image with the Dockerfile that I prepared and tested on Windows Machine

Can somebody help us ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These lines should be together, you're forcing an invalid cache.

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install python-pip
```

Read apt-get tips [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I tried like that. No luck. I got the error message as below.  

E: Unable to locate package python-pip
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get -y install python-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100